# Brew installation does not find PythonInterp even when set

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, sumo

I'm trying to install Sumo via Brew on Mac OS 12.4. I had it previously working, but recently uninstalled and it and now it doesn't seem to like being installed.

When I run `brew install sumo`, the following is the output:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/behradkoohy/Library/Logs/Homebrew/sumo/01.cmake:
--     CMake: 3.23.1
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/gmake
--     Compiler: Clang 13.1.6.13160021
--
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.1_1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.1_1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.23.1_1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:169 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:170 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/sumo-20220526-41647-p2rgj7/sumo-1.13.0/build/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I've tried manually defining PythonInterp/PYTHON_EXECUTABLE, but this doesn't seem to remove the error. Additionally, when I search for similar problems on Stackoverflow, they're all generally related to Make - which I'm not sure how to edit when installing through brew.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Brew to no avail as well.

Comment: Did you install python with brew?

Comment: @Michael I believe I used the default python3 which came with MacOS. I have managed to solve this problem, I'll write up a description now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst not ideal, the solution was found and is as follows:

First, I ran `brew edit sumo` to see what is executed when I run `brew install sumo`.

Somewhere in the middle of the file, there is a definition for `cmake_args`. I added `"-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3"` to this. Once this change was made, the installer no longer complained that it can't find Python_Interp.